# How to open a G Suite add-on sidebar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, gsuite-addons

I have created an add-on sidebar:  https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/cats-quickstart

I use that to send an email, so I have created an email template. So far so good.
Inside my email template there is button.  What I need, is that when the user clicks that button I want to open the add-on (sidebar).

I can’t find anything on Google documentation, so I am not sure if that’s possible or not.
So I would appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Hello @Ago-S, is this link [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/button#setonclickactionaction) of help to you? Moreover, would you mind sharing the code you have? Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 Thanks for your response.
This the button in my email template that I want, onClick, to open the Add-on sidebar:

`' <a href="#" style=""\n' +
'   class="button-a">Open Add-on to do an action\n' +
" </a><br />\n" +`

The link you sent is useful for actions inside the add-on (sidebar). But in my case the user just got the email template with the above button in it, so what I need is that button to trigger the add-on to open

Comment: Hello @Ago-S, how are you creating the email template - are you using AMP? Cheers!